# Polymerfire: No default bucket found

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer

I'm trying to upload data to the storage Bucket of my app but the line `var uploadRef = firebase.storage().ref();` causes the following error:

```
Firebase Storage: No default bucket found. Did you set the 'storageBucket' property when initializing the app?
```

However (I think) I already initialized the app by placing the polymer `<firebase-app>` element in the body of my index.html like so:

```
  <firebase-app
      api-key="<my-api-key>"
      auth-domain="<my-auth-domain>"
      database-url="<my-database-url>"
      storageBucket="<my-storageBucket-url>">
  </firebase-app>
```

I also tried some solutions on the web and have checked:

- that my App Engine APIs are enabled
- that I have the App Engine app enabled
- that firebase-storage@system.gserviceaccount.com is an owner on the storage bucket

By now i don't really know what else to try and would appreciate any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the polymerfire-version provided by the Google web-starter-kit was not the latest one. By the time I found that out I already used the firebase initialization snippet provided on the firebase homepage and therefore don't need the  element anymore.
Now everything works fine.

Comment: where did you put the initialization snippet? In the body or in app.js?